# JavaFX: How to refresh table?

Tags: java, javafx

I have problem with refresh rows styles in JavaFX TableView.

> java version "1.8.0_51"
>
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
>
> Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.51-b03, mixed mode)

Logic:

1. Load data to tableView.
2. Set new styles to rows by setRowFactory.
3. Load new data to table.
4. Refresh styles for new table rows. (Not working for me.)

How to reload styles for rows?

[image]

My code snippet:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class RowFactoryAndOptimisationDemo extends Application {

        VBox root;

        public ObservableList<RFDDomain> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        public TableView<RFDDomain> tableView = new TableView<RFDDomain>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
                root = new VBox();
        root.autosize();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, Color.LINEN);

        stage.setTitle("Row Factory Demo");
        stage.setWidth(500);
        stage.setHeight(300);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        configureTable();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Application.launch(args);
    }

        private void recheck_table() {
            tableView.setRowFactory(new Callback<TableView<RFDDomain>, TableRow<RFDDomain>>() {
            @Override
            public TableRow<RFDDomain> call(TableView<RFDDomain> paramP) {
                    return new TableRow<RFDDomain>() {

                            @Override
                            protected void updateItem(RFDDomain paramT, boolean paramBoolean) {

                                super.updateItem(paramT, paramBoolean);
                                if (!isEmpty()) {
                                    String style = "-fx-control-inner-background: #007F0E;"
                            + "-fx-control-inner-background-alt: #007F0E;";
                                    setStyle(style);
                                }
                            }
                    };
            }
    });
        }



    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void configureTable() {
        int id =1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++) {
            data.add(new RFDDomain(id++,"First Row", "This is for check.", 1));
            data.add(new RFDDomain(id++,"Second Row", null, 2));
            data.add(new RFDDomain(id++,"Third Row", "This is for check.", 3));
            data.add(new RFDDomain(id++,"Fourth Row", "dil", 4));
        }

        tableView.setItems(data);
                recheck_table();


        TableColumn<RFDDomain, Integer> column0 = new TableColumn<RFDDomain, Integer>("Id");
        column0.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<RFDDomain, Integer>("id"));

        TableColumn<RFDDomain, String> column1 = new TableColumn<RFDDomain, String>("Title");
        column1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<RFDDomain, String>("name"));

        TableColumn<RFDDomain, String> column2 = new TableColumn<RFDDomain, String>("Description");
        column2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<RFDDomain, String>("description"));

        TableColumn<RFDDomain, Number> column3 = new TableColumn<RFDDomain, Number>("Status");
        column3.setPrefWidth(55);
        column3.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<RFDDomain, Number>("status"));

        TableColumn<RFDDomain, String> column4 = new TableColumn<RFDDomain, String>("Action");
        column4.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<RFDDomain, String>("name"));

        tableView.getColumns().addAll(column0, column1, column2, column3, column4);

        this.root.getChildren().add(tableView);

                Button button1 = new Button("Load new Data");

                button1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                        data.clear();
                        data.removeAll(data);
                        data.add(new RFDDomain(1,"First Row", "This is for check.", 1));
                        data.add(new RFDDomain(2,"Second Row", null, 2));
                        tableView.setItems(data);
                        recheck_table();
                    }
                });

                this.root.getChildren().add(button1);


    }

    /**
     * Domain Model for this demo.
     */
    public class RFDDomain {
        private SimpleIntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        private SimpleStringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private SimpleStringProperty description = new SimpleStringProperty();
        private SimpleIntegerProperty status = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

        public RFDDomain(int id,String name, String desc, int status) {
            this.id.set(id);
            this.name.set(name);
            this.description.set(desc);
            this.status.set(status);
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id.get();
        }

        public SimpleIntegerProperty idProperty() {
            return id;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description.get();
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty descriptionProperty() {
            return description;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }

        public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getStatus() {
            return status.get();
        }

        public SimpleIntegerProperty statusProperty() {
            return status;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where in your code are you setting rows that are now empty to a plain background?

Comment: button1.setOnAction - set only 2 rows, but style for 3-4 rows are not reload.

Comment: I see in your code where you set the style for rows that contain data, but I don't see where you are setting rows that have changed so that they don't contain data to a plain style.  Btw, why are you calling recheck_table() so much?  You only need to set the row factory once.

Comment: Oh, thanks for right flow... I add: else { this.setStyle("cell indexed-cell table-row-cell"); } to updateItem method and it's work looks like correctly.

Comment: no need to add any more incorrect answers (refresh, hide/show columns, reset items ...  sure you could come up with more <g>): the base problem was an incorrect implementation of updateItem (no else block to revert back to normal), see the OP's last comment

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try `tableView.refresh()`. It's available in JavaFX since Java 8u60.

Comment: no, never-ever use refresh - it's an emergency backout for the extremely rare contexts (as in 0.0000099%) that can't be handles by the normal auto-update mechanisms! @atlantis something's wrong with setup

Comment: Work well for me. It seems that it is the only (simple) way to immediately reflect the changes on the element in backup list of the table view, given the fact that the observable list only exposes the changes on the list, but not the changes on its elements.

Comment: @silverbullettt repeating: if it appears to be necessary, there's something wrong in your setup - in your case that "something" seems to be a missing extractor on the list (which notifies the list of changes to properties of the elements)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little trick i discovered a year ago...

```
myTableView.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(false);
myTableView.getColumns().get(0).setVisible(true);
```

This might not be the best way, but it works for me...

Comment: Is not correct, if you have change in others rows, the method return the table complete to the last state that load the data

Answer (score 1):

Probably no longer relevant, but simply add

```
else { setStyle(null) }
```

to the `updateItem` method in your custom factory - what's happening is that only as many cells are created as are absolutely required to show on the screen (prevents creating unnecessarily many UI elements). These cells are re-used when you scroll through the table by their `updateItem` method. Sometimes (in your case), an existing cell will be updated with `null` to indicate the cell should be empty. You haven't implemented this case, but you should, and you should clear the cell's style.